# Strange .htaccess redirect behavior

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP project with the following folder structure:

- .htaccess
- controller
- model
- dao
- util
- view

  - meta
  - pages
    - .htaccess
    - index.php
    - login.php
    - project.php
    - passwordredefinition.php
    - test123abc123abc.php
    - login.php

My objective is for the user to type on the url "localhost/login" or "localhost/passwordredefinition" and they would be redirected to the login and passwordredefinition respectively.

To achieve this goal, my root .htaccess file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$  view/pages/login [L]
RewriteRule (.*) view/pages/$1 [L]
```

And my view/pages/.htaccess file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

my view/pages/index.php file is something like this:

```
echo "I have been here" // tests purposes
//long script for file inclusions based on the GET parameter
```

If the request is "going through" the index.php, I know because of the "I have been here" on the top of the page.

This was working just fine. `localhost/login` works and `localhost/project` works.  But then I created the `passwordredefinition.php` file. When the url is like this `localhost/passwordredefinition`, it does not go through the `index.php` file, but if I just rename the file to something like this `test123abc123abc.php` and I try `localhost/test123abc123abc` it works just fine.

I have tested it using a lot of file names and for me, this behavior looks like almost random.

So, what I am doing wrong? Please keep in mind that I am new to using .htaccess

Comment: You should probably just set your web server's document root to point to the pages directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that .htaccess is configured at root level to only respond to a certain folder depth. Three folders deep should run fine, but also take in to account that .htaccess files in the parent folders will still affect the files within the folders under it.

I'd suggest scrapping this whole game plan and replace it with a redirection PHP script, similar to what Wordpress does.

All the logic for where to redirect the user could instead be controlled in PHP code, which will give you far greater control - especially if you intend to validate your users.

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /redirect.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**redirect.php:**

```
<?php
function slug_it($in,$folders = true) {
 if (strpos($in,'?')) list($in,$q) = explode('?',$in,2);
 if (strpos($in,'#')) list($in,$q) = explode('#',$in,2);
 $in = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_'.($folders ? '\/' : '').']/','_',$in);
 if ($folders) $in = preg_replace('/[\/]+/','/',$in);
 $in = preg_replace('/[_]+/','_',$in);
 if ($folders) $in = trim($in,'/');
 $in = trim($in,'-');

 return $in;
}

$rewrites = array(
 'login' => 'localhost/login.php',
 'passwordredefinition' => 'localhost/view/pages/passwordredefinition.php',
);

$file = slug_it($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (isset($rewrites[$file])) {
 include($rewrites[$file]);
 exit();
}

include('path_to_404_error_page');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not implemented your code, but it did help me a lot and the solution was much simpler than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` this part means if file exist do not redirect, if you create `test.php` and call `localhost/test.php` it is not going to `index.php` if you call `localhost/test2.php` it will because it is not exist

in your case:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

means if file not exist, redirect to the `[path].php` `localhost/passwordredefinition` gone rewrite to `localhost/passwordredefinition.php`

To testing this, you can create `passwordredefinition` filename without extension and put some text in it. 
The new behavior should:

- `localhost/passwordredefinition` go to the new text file
- `localhost/passwordredefinition.php` go to the php file